# Facebook SDK classes not found Slim Framework

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, composer-php

I am developing an Facebook application with Slim framework, I installed the Facebook SDK with composer

```
  "require" : {
     "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
   }
```

My model looks like this

```
require_once '/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php';

use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

class FBModel{

 private $app_id;
 private $app_secret;
 private $helper;
 private $loginUrl;
 private $session;

  public function __construct() {
     $this->app_id = 'myappid';
     $this->app_secret = 'myappsecret';
     //require_once '../vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php';
     $this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('/login');
     $this->loginUrl = $this->helper->getLoginUrl();
    \Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($this->appId, $this->appSecret);
 }
```

and the model is instantiated inside the index.php file of my application

but it doesn't work properly classes can not be found unless I explicitly both require them and use namespace, even Facebook classes can't find each others, for example I get the following error :

```
  Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found in          
  C:\pathToMyApp\vendor\facebook\php-sdk-v4\src\Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php
```

for getting it working I have to require every single file of Facebook php SDK and also add use and the Facebook\nameofFile of that file, how do I have to solve this issue?

Comment: How does your code look?

Comment: You do know that with composer should just do `require "vendor/autoload.php"`? https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading

Answer (score 1):

With composer you require dependencies with code below. Check documentation about [autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading).

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
```